# How to hide/show button on Node-Red dynamically?

Tags: node-red

Hi I want to disable a button on Node-Red based on a condition. I set the `msg.payload` to `{"buttons":{"hide":["Start Demo"]}}` and sent to ui control node. But this doesn't do anything. How can I hide and show the button based on a condition?

Thanks!